# No suitable decoder module: VLC does not support the audio or video format "undf".

Tags: windows-7, audio, video, vlc-media-player, codec

I'm playing a video in VLC which has dual audio tracks. It runs fine with one track (Language), but when I change to the second audio track, doesn't play the audio and gives the error below:

> "No suitable decoder module: VLC does not support the audio or video format "undf". Unfortunately there is no way for you to fix this."

How do I fix this VLC Media Player error?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What format is "undf"?](http://superuser.com/questions/96794/what-format-is-undf)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It says that there is no audio there basically. Which VLC do you use? Does the movie plays with other soundtrack in an other player like mpc-hc(from CCCP pack) ?

If yes, you can try a fresh VLC build like 1.1.0-pre5 or something (or pre4.. if I remember clearly they are at pre5 already).

Comment: I'm using VLC Media player 1.0.5 Goldeneye.

Comment: Then do what I said, try it with other players for example, or a fresh vlc build.

Comment: Still same problem with latest build http://nightlies.videolan.org/build/win32/branch-20100523-0202/

Comment: Thanks - Now it's working fine in K-Lite Codec Pack 5.9.0 FULL

Comment: People say you should stay away from that. (Not me, I never really used it. Try http://cccp-project.net , or kmplayer. Well.. if it works..^^")

Comment: but CCCP's is looking very old http://cccp-project.net/

Comment: Its actually really new, 2009-09. If you go to the forums, you can fetch an unsupported beta also (2010-05-10)