# VLC does not support the audio or video format "undf" in Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, vlc-media-player, video-codecs

When I play some avi files in my system with `VLC` I get this error:

```
No suitable decoder module:
VLC does not support the audio or video format "undf".
Unfortunately there is no way for you to fix this.
```

I tested other players such as `smplayer`, `totem`, `mplayer` and `Gnome MPlayer` but non of them can play these files.

I'm using `ubuntu 13.04` fully updated with `ubuntu-restricted-extras` installed on a 64 bit multiarch enable machine.

There has been a question about this problem [here](https://superuser.com/questions/144081/no-suitable-decoder-module-vlc-does-not-support-the-audio-or-video-format-undf) but it seems to be for windows user and has an unclear answer.

I asked this question here because I see it as a general Linux problem, not a ubuntu specific one (which should be asked on [AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/)).

Thanks in advance.

**Update:**

The output I get by running `mplayer -identify` command for a file that won't play at all and gives the mentioned error:

```
$ mplayer -identify myVideoFile2013.avi 
MPlayer svn r34540 (Ubuntu), built with gcc-4.7 (C) 2000-2012 MPlayer Team
mplayer: could not connect to socket
mplayer: No such file or directory
Failed to open LIRC support. You will not be able to use your remote control.

Playing myVideoFile2013.avi 
libavformat version 53.21.1 (external)
Mismatching header version 53.19.0
ID_VIDEO_ID=0
libavformat file format detected.
[mp3 @ 0x7fbae9eee540]Header missing
[mp3 @ 0x7fbae9eee540]Header missing
...
[mp3 @ 0x7fbae9eee540]Header missing
[mp3 @ 0x7fbaea7788c0]Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate
ID_AUDIO_ID=0
[lavf] stream 0: audio (mp1), -aid 0
Load subtitles in ./
ID_FILENAME=myVideoFile2013.avi 
ID_DEMUXER=lavf
ID_AUDIO_FORMAT=80
ID_AUDIO_BITRATE=0
ID_AUDIO_RATE=0
ID_AUDIO_NCH=0
ID_START_TIME=unknown
ID_LENGTH=0.00
ID_SEEKABLE=1
ID_CHAPTERS=0
==========================================================================
Requested audio codec family [mpg123] (afm=mpg123) not available.
Enable it at compilation.
Opening audio decoder: [ffmpeg] FFmpeg/libavcodec audio decoders
libavcodec version 53.35.0 (external)
Mismatching header version 53.32.2
[mp2float @ 0x7fbae9eee540]Header missing
[mp2float @ 0x7fbae9eee540]Header missing
[mp2float @ 0x7fbae9eee540]Header missing
[mp2float @ 0x7fbae9eee540]Header missing
[mp2float @ 0x7fbae9eee540]Header missing
[mp2float @ 0x7fbae9eee540]Header missing
Unknown/missing audio format -> no sound
ADecoder init failed :(
Opening audio decoder: [ffmpeg] FFmpeg/libavcodec audio decoders
[mp2 @ 0x7fbae9eee540]Header missing
[mp2 @ 0x7fbae9eee540]Header missing
[mp2 @ 0x7fbae9eee540]Header missing
[mp2 @ 0x7fbae9eee540]Header missing
[mp2 @ 0x7fbae9eee540]Header missing
[mp2 @ 0x7fbae9eee540]Header missing
Unknown/missing audio format -> no sound
ADecoder init failed :(
Requested audio codec family [mad] (afm=libmad) not available.
Enable it at compilation.
Opening audio decoder: [hwmpa] MPEG audio pass-through (fake decoder)
AUDIO: 11025 Hz, 2 ch, mpeg2, 64.0 kbit/18.14% (ratio: 8000->44100)
ID_AUDIO_BITRATE=64000
ID_AUDIO_RATE=11025
ID_AUDIO_NCH=2
Selected audio codec: [hwmpa] afm: hwmpa (MPEG audio pass-through for hardware MPEG decoders)
==========================================================================
AO: [pulse] 11025Hz 2ch s16le (2 bytes per sample)
[format] Sample format big-endian MPEG-2 not yet supported 
[libaf] Reinitialization did not work, audio filter 'format' returned error code -2
[libaf] Unable to setup filter system can not meet sound-card demands, please send a bug report. 
Couldn't find matching filter/ao format!
Audio: no sound
Video: no video

Exiting... (End of file)
ID_EXIT=EOF
```

The output I get by running `mplayer -identify` command for a file that plays for few second and then stops:

```
$ mplayer -identify myVideoFile.avi 
MPlayer svn r34540 (Ubuntu), built with gcc-4.7 (C) 2000-2012 MPlayer Team
mplayer: could not connect to socket
mplayer: No such file or directory
Failed to open LIRC support. You will not be able to use your remote control.

Playing myVideoFile.avi
libavformat version 53.21.1 (external)
Mismatching header version 53.19.0
AVI file format detected.
ID_VIDEO_ID=0
[aviheader] Video stream found, -vid 0
ID_AUDIO_ID=1
[aviheader] Audio stream found, -aid 1
VIDEO:  [XVID]  624x352  24bpp  23.976 fps  1030.6 kbps (125.8 kbyte/s)
Clip info:
 Software: transcode-1.0.6
ID_CLIP_INFO_NAME0=Software
ID_CLIP_INFO_VALUE0=transcode-1.0.6
ID_CLIP_INFO_N=1
Load subtitles in ./
ID_FILENAME=myVideoFile.avi 
ID_DEMUXER=avi
ID_VIDEO_FORMAT=XVID
ID_VIDEO_BITRATE=1030640
ID_VIDEO_WIDTH=624
ID_VIDEO_HEIGHT=352
ID_VIDEO_FPS=23.976
ID_VIDEO_ASPECT=0.0000
ID_AUDIO_FORMAT=85
ID_AUDIO_BITRATE=128000
ID_AUDIO_RATE=0
ID_AUDIO_NCH=0
ID_START_TIME=0.00
ID_LENGTH=1265.43
ID_SEEKABLE=0
ID_CHAPTERS=0
Failed to open VDPAU backend libvdpau_nvidia.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
[vdpau] Error when calling vdp_device_create_x11: 1
==========================================================================
Opening video decoder: [ffmpeg] FFmpeg's libavcodec codec family
libavcodec version 53.35.0 (external)
Mismatching header version 53.32.2
Unsupported PixelFormat 61
Unsupported PixelFormat 53
Unsupported PixelFormat 81
Selected video codec: [ffodivx] vfm: ffmpeg (FFmpeg MPEG-4)
==========================================================================
ID_VIDEO_CODEC=ffodivx
==========================================================================
Requested audio codec family [mpg123] (afm=mpg123) not available.
Enable it at compilation.
Opening audio decoder: [ffmpeg] FFmpeg/libavcodec audio decoders
AUDIO: 48000 Hz, 2 ch, floatle, 128.0 kbit/4.17% (ratio: 16000->384000)
ID_AUDIO_BITRATE=128000
ID_AUDIO_RATE=48000
ID_AUDIO_NCH=2
Selected audio codec: [ffmp3float] afm: ffmpeg (FFmpeg MPEG layer-3 audio)
==========================================================================
AO: [pulse] 48000Hz 2ch floatle (4 bytes per sample)
ID_AUDIO_CODEC=ffmp3float
Starting playback...
Movie-Aspect is 1.77:1 - prescaling to correct movie aspect.
ID_VIDEO_ASPECT=1.7727
VO: [xv] 624x352 => 624x352 Planar YV12 
A:  20.2 V:  20.2 A-V:  0.000 ct: -0.042 485/485  3%  0%  0.5% 0 0 
[mpeg4 @ 0x7f6d41dbf540]dc marker bit missing
[mpeg4 @ 0x7f6d41dbf540]Error at MB: 386
[mpeg4 @ 0x7f6d41dbf540]marker does not match f_code
[mpeg4 @ 0x7f6d41dbf540]ac-tex damaged at 17 2
[mpeg4 @ 0x7f6d41dbf540]Error at MB: 97
[mpeg4 @ 0x7f6d41dbf540]marker does not match f_code
[mpeg4 @ 0x7f6d41dbf540]marker does not match f_code
[mpeg4 @ 0x7f6d41dbf540]cbpc damaged at 13 17
[mpeg4 @ 0x7f6d41dbf540]Error at MB: 693
[mpeg4 @ 0x7f6d41dbf540]marker does not match f_code
[mpeg4 @ 0x7f6d41dbf540]marker does not match f_code
[mpeg4 @ 0x7f6d41dbf540]ac-tex damaged at 14 2
[mpeg4 @ 0x7f6d41dbf540]Error at MB: 94
[mpeg4 @ 0x7f6d41dbf540]marker does not match f_code
[mpeg4 @ 0x7f6d41dbf540]marker does not match f_code
[mpeg4 @ 0x7f6d41dbf540]Error at MB: 532
[mpeg4 @ 0x7f6d41dbf540]marker does not match f_code
[mpeg4 @ 0x7f6d41dbf540]marker does not match f_code
[mpeg4 @ 0x7f6d41dbf540]ac-tex damaged at 14 2
[mpeg4 @ 0x7f6d41dbf540]Error at MB: 94
[mpeg4 @ 0x7f6d41dbf540]marker does not match f_code
[mpeg4 @ 0x7f6d41dbf540]concealing 858 DC, 858 AC, 858 MV errors
A:  20.2 V:  20.2 A-V: -0.017 ct: -0.045 486/486  3%  0%  0.5% 0 0 
Exiting... (End of file)
ID_EXIT=EOF
```

Comment: AVI is a container format - it would help to know the actual audio codec. You probably don't have the right decoder installed.

Comment: @user55325 how can I find out about the right codec to install?

Comment: Good question. If vlc doesn't work, you could try `ffprobe` or `mplayer -identify`. But I feel like these are unlikely to work if VLC doesn't recognize it.

Comment: @user55325 non of what you said are available in my ubuntu repository. How can I get them?

Comment: `mplayer` should definitely be available if it isn't already installed. Oddly, `ffprobe` doesn't seem to be available on 13.04 (I'm still running the most recent LTS release here). You can find source for it at the FFmpeg project [repository](http://ffmpeg.org/download.html), if you want to compile it yourself.

Comment: @user55325 my apology. mplayer is indeed installed. I used it to run the file and got error about `[mp3] Header missing` and `[mpeg4]marker does not match f_code`. updated the post with output. Thanks for your replies.

Comment: `undf` seems like shortcut for undefined. I would say this file belongs to `/dev/null`.

Comment: @mvp That was my guess about "undf" but what do you mean about belonging to `/dev/null`? I'm not sure if my file is OK. it may be corrupted but I used bittorrent to download it and torrent has a inclusive checksum mechanism.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What format is "undf"?](http://superuser.com/questions/96794/what-format-is-undf)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally I found the answer. The problem is with the files. I **got corrupted files**. after checking files checksum I found my files to be corrupted.

```
$md5sum myVideoFile.avi   #the one that gives the error
2ff0cc68fcc51ce79c0692c3df2b2228  myVideoFile.avi
$md5sum originalVideoFile.avi 
4133330d6abc8276c8feb332a211424b  originalVideoFile.avi
```

All files with error was corrupted. After getting the files again everything works fine with no error.