# I was recording by hypercam when my computer closed, I dont know how to play this UNDF file

Tags: windows-7

I was recording with a hypercam, then my computer closed (empty battery), the file is over 2 GB. Is there no way to get back anything of this file? I know there is no media player to play UNDF, but is there really nothing left of the whole file? Its very important so i really hope someone can help me out here!

Comment: UNDF means that the information needed to decode the file was not written to it, so your media player cannot work out what it is.  Try the tips here: http://superuser.com/questions/96794/what-format-is-undf