# how to play a "undf" file in vlc media player?

Tags: vlc-media-player, wav

I have a wave file. When I open it with VLC player it gives result

> VLC does not support the audio or video format "undf". Unfortunately there is no way for you to fix this.

How can I play this file?

Comment: If VLC says "undf" it means "undefined". In other words it doesn't recognize the audio-content of the WAV file as a supported format. (WAV is a container definition. There can be several possible content versions in that container.) If you can supply the first 32 bytes of the file as a hex-dump I can probably figure out what application is supposed to be able to understand this particular file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What format is "undf"?](http://superuser.com/questions/96794/what-format-is-undf)