# Unable to play .wmv file on VLC

Tags: vlc-media-player, wmv

I have downloaded some video and when I try to play on VLC it shows me:

```
No suitable decoder module:
VLC does not support the audio or video format "PRDY". 
Unfortunately there is no way for you to fix this.

No suitable decoder module:
VLC does not support the audio or video format "undf". 
Unfortunately there is no way for you to fix this.
```

Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Related: http://superuser.com/questions/96794/what-format-is-undf . Bottom line, the codec embedded on the WMV file isn't supported on VLC. It should play natively with Windows Media Player, unless it is damaged.

Comment: @DoktoroReichard WMV embeds actual executable CODECs into the video file? Really?

Answer (score 1):

Let's look on this: http://www.headbands.com/gspot/ . This should help you to found out which codecs are missing, etc. Than you should download specific codecs for your media player.

I also found thread on one forum to VLC that it could be problem when you use 64-bit system. It is older thread but it maybe helps you: https://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?t=39675

Comment: VLC doesn't require any external codecs so GSpot will not be useful.

Answer (score 1):

**Issue**

Same issue reported at the following locations:

[VideoLan Forums](https://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?t=4357)

[Stream Recorder Forum](http://stream-recorder.com/forum/www-feyenoord-nl-cant-download-silverlight-videos-t6783.html?s=c8d4564963ca76c9ea66b596f124e303&)

No answer included in the forum posts one from 2004 and one from 2010.

On the VLC forum it states:

> VLC does NOT play everything and nowhere does it state it does so.
>
> We don't support this codec, unfortunately.

**Alternative Software**

I personally use K-Lite Mega Codec Pack in conjunction with Media Player Classic HC, I cannot confirm it contains the relevant codecs for what you are trying to play however I have never had it fail.

[K-Lite Coded Pack](http://www.codecguide.com/download_kl.htm)

Answer (score 0):

PRDY is a format for DRM protection.
You need a decode key but its not free in most cases.
If your file is pirated, its trash that cannot be played.
If you purchased, get the player from the same website.
VLC does not support it.